# How can I add element of a list in loop elegantly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

It's a simple question.Here is a example:

Data:

```
score = [10, 20]
weight = [0.2, 0.8]
```

Here is my code:

```
score = [10, 20]
weight = [0.2, 0.8]
score_list = []
for i, k1 in enumerate(score):
    k_score = 100 if k1 < 20 else 95
    k_score *= weight[i]
    score_list.append(k_score)
sum_score = sum(score_list)
```

Use the code above I can get want I want,but I think it's not elegent,I want to adjust,can u give some advice?

Comment: `for w, k in zip(weight, score):` is an alternative to the enumerate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just take a running sum instead of storing each separate value in `score_list`:

```
score = [10, 20]
weight = [0.2, 0.8]
sum_score = 0

for i, k1 in enumerate(score):
    k_score = 100 if k1 < 20 else 95
    k_score *= weight[i]
    sum_score += k_score

print(sum_score)
```

Comment: Fine, Is there anything else that can be improved？

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are trying numpy, you can basically get the `dot product` i.e

```
score = np.array(score)
output = np.dot(np.where(score<20,100,95),weights)

print(output)
96
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, Hope this will help :

```
sum([100*wei if sco < 20 else 95*wei for sco,wei in zip(score,weight)])
```

Ouput:

```
96.0
```